# cordova app to watch data from bluetooth low energy like nRF UART App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to do an hybrid app like [nRF UART App](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Nordic-mobile-Apps/nRF-UART-App) with cordova.
i can connect and disconnect, but i don't know how to catch the data every time the ble send.

i'm using this plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central
it's a Nordic Semicondutor that send temperatura every 3 seconds.
it's gona be a function to an intel XDK app.

```
ble.read(device_id, "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E", "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E",
function(data){
    data = (typeof(data)=="object")? JSON.stringify(data): data;
    alert(data);
}, fail);
```

does anyone have an idea? thanks

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have a similar issue I'm trying to resolve